# How to use the argument of a function to determine which class to call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

Let's say we have a bunch of monster classes, which include a Goblin and an Imp:

```
class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = "Goblin"
        self.HP = random.randint(15,20)
        self.Damage = random.randint(5,10)

class Imp(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.Name = "Imp"
            self.HP = random.randint(5,10)
            self.Damage = random.randint(2,5)
```

And we have a function that creates monsters, where "Type" will be the type of monster being created:

```
def GenerateCharacter(Type, Number):

    i=0
    while i < (Number):
        TempChar = #what do I put here so it knows to create Goblins if I do GenerateCharacter(Goblin, 10)

        Character_List.append(TempChar)
        i = i + 1
```

How do I make it so that the class being put into TempChar is a Goblin if the Type argument of the function is "Goblin", the name of the class? So that if I do GenerateCharacter(X, 10), it does TempChar = X() ??

If I do GenerateCharacter(Goblin, 10), I would want it to generate 10 instances of the Goblin class and append to Character_List, but if I do GenerateCharacter(Imp, 10) I would want it to do 10 imps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're passing in the name of the class as a string, try something like this:

```
def GenerateCharacter(Type, Number):
    i=0
    while i < (Number):
        if Type == "Goblin":
            TempChar = Goblin()
        elif Type == "Imp":
            TempChar = Imp()
        # Etc. for every type of monster you have 
        Character_List.append(TempChar)
        i += 1
```

There is perhaps a better way to do this by encapsulating the types Goblin and Imp in a Monster class, which may make your code a little easier to maintain going forward. See here for more info and an example: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Edit: Here is much closer to what you want:

```
list_of_monsters = []

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print "foo created"

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        print "bar created"

class Fubar:
    def __init__(self, num, word):
        print "Fubar created"
        self.number = num
        self.phrase = word

def create_monster(class_name, *args):
    local_class = class_name(*args)
    list_of_monsters.append(local_class)

create_monster(Foo)
create_monster(Bar)

# You can even pass in arguments:
create_monster(Fubar, 1, "Hello")

print list_of_monsters
```

If you inspect this code, you will see that list_of_monsters will contain 3 objects, one of each class.

Comment: Let's say we have hundreds of types of monsters: I'd need hundreds of if statements. 

Is there any way to do this without the if statement? By taking directly Type from the argument and putting it where "Goblin" is in the "TempChar = Goblin()" statement? 

So that if I do GenerateCharacter(X, 10), it does TempChar = X() ??

Comment: Well, if you're passing in the argument as a string, there is no way to do that, as X in your example will be of type string, which is not callable. You would have to pass in the constructor function itself as the argument in order to call it that way.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that? Still not sure

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, that does exactly what I need. It was the *args part that I was missing, and I still kind of have no idea what that really means. Looks like I've got some research to do

Comment: @pomtree, it's very possible to create objects from strings...see my answer

Comment: @danidee I was not aware of globals(), and you are correct in that it can be used to create objects as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you're passing it as a string, you can use the `globals()` method which returns a dictionary of all the variables in the global namespace

```
def GenerateCharacter(Type, Number):
    Character_List = []
    for i in range(Number):
        name = Type
        TempChar = globals()[name](name)

        Character_List.append(TempChar)

    return Character_List
```

also create the Character_List outside the loop and use a for loop, because it's cleaner and you avoid incrementing the counter of the loop yourself.

Comment: The globals() method returns an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    GenerateCharacter2(Goblin, 10)
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 39, in GenerateCharacter2
    TempChar = globals()[name](name)
KeyError: "<class '__main__.Goblin'>"

Comment: That's because you're passing in the object, pass the the name as a string `GenerateCharacter('Goblin', 10)`